# macro to unmerge the cells between the blank cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a master sheet that contains all the days info. I want to copy those info to another sheet based on the day selected that is mentioned in `column C`. I am able to copy the `column B` good but not `column A` as `column A` is having some merged cells. Please see the attachment and help me to get the code.

[image]

so far my code is as below

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim Acell As String
Dim Bcell As String
Dim Ccell As String
Dim cellA As String
Dim cellB As String

i = 1
a = 1
k = 1

For j = 1 To 100
    Acell = "A" & j
    Bcell = "B" & i
    Ccell = "C" & j
    cellB = "B" & k

    celltext = Sheets(1).Range(Ccell)

    If IsEmpty(Sheets(1).Range(Ccell).Value) = True Then
        ' need the code here
        k = k + 1
    ElseIf celltext Like "*all*" Then
        Sheets(1).Range(Bcell).Copy Sheets(2).Range(cellB)
        k = k + 1
    ElseIf celltext Like "*bd4*" Then
        Sheets(1).Range(Bcell).Copy Sheets(2).Range(cellB)
        k = k + 1
    End If

    i = i + 1
Next
```

result should be like this 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAno5.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure what's your final result like: show an examples

Comment: Added the expected result in the main query

Comment: where do you grab the "day" to fetch your data by?

Comment: sheet1 is the master data that in manually updated once in awhile. result should be in sheet2.

Comment: please check the result now. i modified it.

Comment: I don't get the criteria to be used to select rows in sheet1: why Job3 hasn't be selected at all? why Job1 "mon" hasn't been selected?

Comment: i have buttons like mon,tue,wed...sun. if i click mon, jobs having column C as all and mon should be populated in respective A and B columns of sheet2

Comment: please check the result in the main query

Comment: I took the liberty of indenting your code with [Rubberduck's SmartIndenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation) so that it's actually readable. Full disclosure, I'm a contributor to that project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm what I did was this

1. Loop through the merged cells to get the job (cells which are merged only have values in the first cell. The rest are empty)
2. Insert the job
3. Merge them again to get the format you wanted

   ```
   Dim a As Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim j As Integer
   Dim k As Integer
   Dim Acell As String
   Dim Bcell As String
   Dim Ccell As String
   Dim cellA As String
   Dim cellB As String

   i = 1
   k = 1

   For j = 1 To 100
      Acell = "A" & j
      Bcell = "B" & i
      Ccell = "C" & j
      cellB = "B" & k
      cellA = "A" & k
      jobRow = j
      celltext = Sheets(1).Range(Ccell)

      If IsEmpty(Sheets(1).Range(Ccell).Value) = True Then
         ' need the code here
          k = k + 1
      ElseIf celltext Like "*all*" Or celltext Like "*bd4*" Then
          Sheets(1).Range(Bcell).Copy Sheets(2).Range(cellB)

          'get jobs
          Do Until sheets(1).Cells(jobRow, 1) <> ""
             jobRow = jobRow - 1
          Loop
          Sheets(2).Range(cellA).Value = sheets(1).Cells(jobRow, 1)

          k = k + 1
      End If

      i = i + 1
   Next j

   'merge cells
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   For r = 1 To k
       Set cellTop = Sheets(2).Cells(r, 1)
       rowsBelow = r

       If cellTop.Value <> "" Then
          Do
             rowsBelow = rowsBelow + 1
          Loop Until cellTop.Value <> Sheets(2).Cells(rowsBelow, 1)

          Set cellBottom = Sheets(2).Cells(rowsBelow - 1, 1)
          Sheets(2).Range(cellTop, cellBottom).Merge

          r = rowsBelow
       End If
    Next r

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
   ```

Comment: got an error 1004 at this step  Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(jobRow, 1) <> ""

Comment: oh because it was referencing to activesheet. I changed it to sheets(1) instead. Try again.

Comment: it did work after changing the activesheet to sheet(1). is there any way to delete the blank rows in sheet(2) after all the work is done. 
i would be much more happy if the outcome is similar to that of the result mentioned in the main query

Comment: hmm you can try looping through column A or B to check if the cell is empty. If empty, then delete the entire row.

Comment: i googled and found this code which didn;t work. Can u pls help me in removing the empty rows.

Comment: Dim i As Long 



 'We turn off calculation and screenupdating to speed up the macro.

 With Application

  .Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  .ScreenUpdating = False

      

 'We work backwards because we are deleting rows.

 For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

  If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(i)) = 0 Then

   Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

  End If

 Next i



  .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

  .ScreenUpdating = True

  End With

End Sub

Comment: Hmm try this instead. 
     For r = 1 to k  'loop through rows
             If  Sheets(2).cells(r,1).value = "" then 'check if column A is empty
                      Sheets(2).cells(r,1).entirerow.delete
             end if
      Next r